# HTML JS Popup Window inside curent window

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create something like a pop-up window every time I click on my marker; the pop-up window will be inside the current window, but with the rest of the window fully working.

Starting from this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZhon.jpg
If I click the marker I want to achieve something like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wh1Gd.jpg

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height:100%;">
<body style="height:100%;margin:0;padding:0;">
    <div id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
    <script>
    var map;
        function myMap() {
            var mapProp= {
                center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
                zoom:5,
            };
            map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function TCPConnection()
        {

            var connection = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8001');
            // When the connection is open, send some data to the server
            connection.onopen = function () {
                connection.send('Ping'); // Send the message 'Ping' to the server
            };

            // Log errors
            connection.onerror = function (error) {
                console.log('WebSocket Error ' + error);
            };
            var contentString = '<p><b>TEST</b></p>'
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: contentString
            });

            // Log messages from the server
            connection.onmessage = function (e) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: {lat: 51.508742, lng:-0.120850},
                    map: map,
                    title: 'Test marker',
                    label: 'A'
                });
                marker.addListener('click',function(){
                    infoWindow.open(map,marker);
                    alert("Test\nTest?");

                });
                console.log('Server: ' + e.data);

            };
        }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[MYKEY]&callback=myMap"></script>
    <script> TCPConnection();</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is pretty easy to resolve with css and a little bit of javascript (if needed).

> HTML

```
<div id="myPopUp">
    TEST
</div>
```

> CSS

```
#myPopUp {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background-color: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
  border-radius: 3px;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

> Javascript

```
function showPopUp(x, y, text, duration) {
  var myPopUp = document.getElementById("myPopUp");
  myPopUp.style.display = 'block';
  myPopUp.style.left = x + 'px';
  myPopUp.style.top = y + 'px';
  myPopUp.innerHTML = text;
  if (duration) { // duration in ms *optionnal
    window.setTimeout(hidePopUp, duration);
  }
}

function hidePopUp() {
  var myPopUp = document.getElementById("myPopUp");
  myPopUp.style.display = 'none';
}
```

When you add your click event on the marker you can have an event in argument of your callback. Position of the click (or marker) should be in it.

```
marker.addListener('click',function(event){
 infoWindow.open(map,marker);
 console.log(event); // look in the console to find the position you need
 showPopUp(100,100, 'I m here :D', 5000);
 // then call the function showPopUp with the good args
});
```

> Animation

You can add pretty animation to your popup like this:

```
#myPopUp {
  top: -100vh,
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background-color: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: top 0.3s;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

Now in showPopUp and hidePopUp you remove the display assignatio line. Then you add to hidePopUp this:

```
myPopUp.style.top = '-100vh';
```

You can change the direction of animation by using left property or by changing the default value of top / left style. You can also play with opacity or transform to have advanced animations.

Comment: perhaps the z-index, I'm gonna test it.

Comment: I correct some stuff (look at my edit). You can call the showPopUp function in the javascript console: showPopUp(100,100, 'I m here :D', 5000); It's working for me.

Comment: It was a pleasure ! :D